# Vuejs v-for on table with split cells

Tags: html, vue.js

how would I implement the v-for tag correctly for the following HTML table structure? I am interested in repeating the foreach file in files. Adding v-for to the "tr html tag: does not give me the expected result

```
  <table border="1" align="right" width="200">
        <thead style="background-color: #87cefa;">
        <tr class="uppercase">
            <th> File Name</th>
            <th> Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">File#1</td>
            <td>top right</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>bottom right</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it like this

```
<table border="1" align="right" width="200">
    <thead style="background-color: #87cefa;">
        <tr class="uppercase">
            <th> File Name</th>
            <th> Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody v-for="(file,index) in 5">
        <tr >
            <td rowspan="2">File#{{index}}</td>
            <td>top right</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>bottom right</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78ztjjkn/)